# Add 'only telecommute' and 'offering relocation' checkboxes to search box on home page

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I suspect my title is probably sufficient, but my reason is this:

The first thing I do when I get to careers.stackoverflow.com is click a blank search so I can get the 'only telecommute' filter.  It would be nice if I could skip the page load and the extra click.